# Interconversion between Complex Number Forms

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

Suppose we give an oscillatory force $\Re{(F)}$, where $F=F_0 \text{e}^{\text{i}\omega t}$, onto a system, which responds with a velocity $\Re{(v)}$, where $v=v_0 \text{e}^{\text{i}\omega t}$. ($F_0$ and $v_0$ are complex numbers as well.)

The power input $P$ is therefore $P=\Re{(F)}\Re{(v)}$. How can I write $P$ in the form $\Re{(A\text{e}^{\text{i}\alpha(t)}+B)}$ instead, where $A$ and $B$ are constants?

- $\Re{(x)}$ denotes "$\text{Re}(x)$."

I tried the identity $\Re{(z)}=\frac{1}{2}(z+z^*)$, but that doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: a first attempt is to represent each complex number in the form $a + bi$, and if it's a function, then to represent as $x(t) + iv(t)$, where $x(t)$ and $v(t)$ are real functions, as well as $a, b$.

Another Hint: to simplify, it's good also to remember that $(a + bi)(c+di) = (ac-bd)+ i(ad+bd)$.

Comment: Thanks a lot! By the way, it should be $ac+bd$ not $ad+bd$ in the last formula.

Comment: Actually it's right the formula.